# Big O notation of a program (Worst-Case)

Tags: java, big-o, complexity-theory

I have a question regarding complexity theory. If I have a Bubble sort algorithm and I want to find its worst case running time Big O, we can conclude that it is O(n^2). Now, what about If I have a program that executes different operations  like a sorting algorithm, search algorithm, etc. How do I know what is the worst case running time (Big O) of this program in general.

For example, how having different algorithms within a program with its respective worst case running time Big O notations get to the conclusion of the worst case running time (Big O) of the entire program. Like when a program has the following: O(n^2), O(1), O(n).... Which one of these notations is the one that represents the entire program?

How would you find the worst-case running time Big O of this program?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Prog1 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    int first = 0;
    int last;
    int middle;
    int search;
    int[] array;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Number of elements");
    int n = input.nextInt();

    array = new int[n];

    System.out.println("Enter " + n + " value ");
    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
        array[x] = input.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("Value to search");
    search = input.nextInt();

    last = n - 1;
    middle = (first + last) / 2;

    while (first <= last) {
        if (array[middle] < search)
            first = middle + 1;
        else if (array[middle] == search) {
            System.out.println(" Number " + search + " is in the array");
            break;
        } else
            last = middle - 1;

        middle = (first + last) / 2;
    }
    if (first > last)
        System.out.println(" Number " + search + " is not in the list.");
 }
}
```

Comment: Well, what is the asymptotic growth of the *entire* program, with respect to `n`?

Answer (score 3):

The highest one. O(n^2) + O(n) + O(1) = O(n^2) asymptotically talking! 
This is how you would calculate the complexity of an algorithm though. 
It doesn't make much sense to talk about program "complexity".

Comment: Why did you chose O(n^2) over the other two?

Comment: @Plrr It's not a choice.

Comment: @Pirr check this out http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/f/3/b/f3b82062abf7b259e0a7638b3d1b5e85.png

Comment: I know... I just want to know why. I know that you specified "The highest one" in your post.But the thing is that I don't understand how the highest one represents the worst-case running time Big O of this program.

Comment: @Plrr It's the definition of Big-O notation and complexity. When N is big enough the only term that matters is the one with the highest exponent. That determines the overall complexity. You should consider to better study the theory.